# Win 10 Share with NextCloud

Tags: windows-10, nextcloud

I installed on my computer NextCloud (We use it at work) and I noticed that I should have a share with NextCloud option to share the content (file) with another our NextCloud user.
Like this:

[image]

Version that I am using: 2.5.2.5231

The share that I am talking about is when I right click on the file there should be an option as NextCloud or Share with NextCloud.

Any advice and recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall Nextcloud. Do not move or rename the Nextcloud program-files directory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and I still dont know where it was the problem.
First I tried with older version of NextCloud (uninstalled the previous never one). It worked.
Second I downloaded the latest version and installed it (deleted the older version). It worked.

I also checked and I was logged in NextCloud before also. So I dont have a real explanation what was the problem.

Thanks again and have a good time :slight_smile: